# Python ImportError using F2py

Tags: python, python-import, f2py

I have two F90 files that I want to use with python, so I'm using f2py to compile them (together) and result a python module, I'm doing it like this:

```
f2py -c ControlParameters.F90 vector.F90 -m test
```

When I do this, everything is fine, and I can use functions and subroutines from those files with python.

But now, I need to use f2py with those two files, adding a couple of libraries, like `-liomp5` or `-lzmumps`, I get the python module like in the upper case, but when I try to import it from python I have the following error:

```
ImportError: /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.so: undefined symbol: MPI_Finalize
```

There are some libraries that cannot be used with f2py?

Comment: Put a fortran tag also